# не могу подключить библиотеку SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

[image: неразрешенный внешний символ]
пытаюсь подключить библиотеку SFML,вроде сделал все как в гайде на официальном сайте, но почему то не хочет запускаться, выдает эти ошибки, что делать?

Comment: это пробный код с самого сайте sfml

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос задан некорректно. Однако чтобы решить проблему проверьте настройки проекта в Visual Studio:

1. `<C/C++>/<Общие>/<Дополнительные каталоги включения>`, там должна быть папка `include` библиотеки.
2. `<Компоновщик>/<Общие>/<Дополнительные каталоги библиотек>`, там должна быть папка `lib` библиотеки.
3. `<Компоновщик>/<Ввод>/<Дополнительные зависимости>`, там должны быть `lib` файлы библиотеки, которые будут использоваться при компиляции.